# Define custom property of type date and use it in query

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

The professional version of Artifactory allows to define custom properties for artifacts. Usually, these are key/value pairs where the value is a String.

Is it also possible to use dates (or numbers) as value?

I would like to define a property like "doNotUseAfter" with a date. Then I would like to use the Artifactory query language to find out which artifacts have a doNotUseAfter date that is already in the past.

Answer (score 4):

All property values are strings, or collections of strings. There is no type information built-in to properties. However, if you format your dates as strings using a sortable encoding (such as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), you can use an AQL query to string-compare to the current date in the same format.

For example, if your artifact has a property `doNotUseAfter: 2018-10-22`, you can use the following AQL query to find it:

```
items.find({"@doNotUseAfter": {"$lt": "2019-02-01"}})
```

---

Note that AQL does have specific support for date and numeric data, but as far as I can tell, that only applies to fields like `modified` or `size` that always have those types; I'm fairly certain it doesn't parse arbitrary properties as one type or another based on formatting. This could cause problems when sorting or comparing numeric properties, since the string `"5"` is considered larger than `"43"` for example, but for dates and timestamps in a sortable format, there is no such issue.